# Strategy in Navara gambit

Tags: opening, reti-opening, hypermodernism

I am playing few years strictly 1.Nf3 with the intention to play Reti Opening. In my last OTB game I experience Navara Gambit (from a Czech GM David Navara) in Reti Advanced variation:

```
[FEN " "]
1.Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. b4 g5
```

Looking at it I made a conclusion not to take the pawn as White would be in not ideal position (playable though):

```
[FEN "Greedy variation"]
1.Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. b4 g5 4. Nxg5 e5 5. d3 Bxb4+ 6. Bd2 Bxd2 7. Qxd2
```

So in order to avoid that situation I played 4. Qb3 and after 4. ... g4 I would simply take the d-pawn

```
[FEN ""]
1.Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. b4 g5 4.Qb3 g4? 5. Nxd4 Qxd4 6. Bb2
```

So my game went like this

```
[FEN ""]
1.Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. b4 g5 4.Qb3 Bg7 5. Nxg5 e5 6. d3 a5 ...
```

The result is not important for this question. I also played few variations in Navara gambit (with my friend) and it looks solid for White and Black (this is subjective opinion of ~1600elo player).

**My question is: What would be the general strategic idea for 4.Qb3?** *Stockish 15 in 60 depth also suggests 4.g3 (as the ideal move ~+0.5) move what seem too passive in my eyes.*

I appreciate any source, experience or idea

Comment: 1. I agree that 4. Ng5 is not good. Black wins the pawn back with 4...e5 (5. Nf3 e4 !) and probably has even an advantage. 2. What about 4.Bb2 ? I did not ask the engine yet. 3. g3 is a positional move (idea Bg2 and O-O) , but in fact quite calm. 4. Qb3 is an interesting move. It covers the b4-pawn and also the Bb2 should White play Bb2 which is crucial in the above line. But I do not think that White can hope for an advantage with this move. I currently run a math program , I will let run the engine later.

Comment: My Engine (not the newest!) actually suggests 4. Qb3 (depth 34) 0.68 , then h3 (0.45) , then Qa4 (0.37). After 4.Ng5 e5 the evaluation is -0.05 after 5.d3.

Comment: This isn't really a proper gambit, since taking leads to an inferior position. Engine analysis (37 moves depth, SF14+) give a slight edge to white after g5, Qa4+ or h3. The Navara gambit is a recent line with some studies and videos available. It's played by players with elos above 2700, so it's pretty solid with the current knowledge. With my mortal skills I would prefer the Qa4+ line (+0.2) which leads to a safer K position for white and K safety issues for black. The g3 line (+0.4) creates K safety issues for both sides. The h3 line (+0.2) leads to safe positions for both players.